# Where I can find a list of all query plan operators in Postgres?

Tags: postgresql, documentation, sql-execution-plan

I can't find in Postgres documentation a list of all operators, that can appear in query plans, such as Nested Loops, Seq Scan, Index Only Scan etc. Please, help me!

I googled really hard and found many sites, but not official docs

Answer (score 0):

The best I can find is [20.7.1. Planner Method Configuration](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/15/runtime-config-query.html#RUNTIME-CONFIG-QUERY-ENABLE) about how to enable or disable plan types, but does not explain them.

AFAIK the documentation for various scan modes is scattered around the PostgreSQL documentation. You'll have to search for each plan type. Here's some.

- [Chapter 11. Indexes](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/indexes.html)
- [Bitmap index scans](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/indexes-bitmap-scans.html)
- [Index only scans](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/15/indexes-index-only-scans.html)
- [Parallel Plans](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/15/parallel-plans.html)

You can also find detailed information on the [PostgreSQL Wiki](https://wiki.postgresql.org/wiki/Main_Page).

Answer (score 0):

The best place to search most complete and up to date list of plan node operations is PostgreSQL sources. For actual versions it's `ExplainNode` function in `explain.c`.

For PostgreSQL 16.1 (latest stable version at this moment) see this link: https://github.com/postgres/postgres/blob/REL_16_1/src/backend/commands/explain.c#L1178